# ExpressJS - What does inspect do and can someone please explain this code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I started learning ExpressJS so some things are not very clear yet.

Code:

```
app.post("/stats", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.statuses) {
    const { recipient_id, status } = req.body.statuses[0];
    inspect("status message: ")(
      `recipient_id: ${recipient_id}, status: ${status}`
    );
    return res.json({ status: "ok" });
  } else {
    return res.status(501).send("sorry");
  }
});
```

Request to the /stats endpoint:

```
{
  "statuses": [
    {
      "id": "ABGGFlA5FpafAgo6tHcNmNjXmuSf",
      "status": "sent",
      "timestamp": "1518694700",
      "message": {
        "recipient_id":"16315555555"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

These three lines are the ones I find very confusing.

```
const { recipient_id, status } = req.body.statuses[0];
        inspect("status message: ")(
          `recipient_id: ${recipient_id}, status: ${status}`
```

I understand that we check if the rrequest coming has a "statuses" key in the body then we go through the if block otherwise reply "sorry".
Can someone kindly explain what those three lines above do.
For example, how can you have pass the request into a const variable that is a json.

```
const { recipient_id, status } = req.body.statuses[0];
```

Thanks

Comment: `{recipient_id}` should be wrong since it is inside the message field you can destructure it directly. has to be like `{message:{recipient_id},status}`

Comment: inspect is probably a debugging function

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion and yes, you're right about the recipient_id. I made a mistake.

So would inspect look like this:
```const {message:{ recipient_id }, status} = req.body.statuses[0];
        inspect("status message: ")(
          recipient_id: ${message:{recipient_id}}, status: ${status}```

Comment: inspect looks like a debugging function. i don't see the point of keeping it if it is so